# HTML inside sprintf

Tags: php, html, php-5.3

Is it possible to do something equivalent to this in [PHP >= 5.3.0](http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php)?

```
echo sprintf(_('By %s'), ?>
    <span class="author-name"><?php echo $authorName; ?></span>
<?php ); ?>
```

If I use said syntax I receive the following error, which is being caused by the first `?>`,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' in ...

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to insert HTML with [PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) inside, as a parameter for the [`sprintf` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) *without* treating the HTML as a string (`'<span class="author-name">' . $authorName . '</span>'`).

Comment: One word: **Nope**. Well, unless you want to mess with the buffer, in which case... just forget it.

Comment: @JosephSilber Dammit, I thought PHP was flexible enough to pull it off.

Comment: Flexibility also has its limits.

Comment: @JosephSilber I guess so. If you answer a big bold 'nope' I'll accept it as an answer.